# Use mouse cursor in virtual bkx and host at same time

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am running scripts inside a virtualbox vm and this script requires a cursor to click on objects. I was wondering is I can somehow fake the cursor and have my mouse working on host and another cursor being in the vm being captured by the script.

Comment: While I am not familiar with AutoIt, it is described as a scripting language that can virtually move a mouse within a GUI. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: It would need a 3rd party solution as described above. What you want is not native to Virtual Box or VMware.